# gganimate: some points stay, others transition

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm making a gganimate object, and would like points from one geom_point to transition, and points from another geom_point object (which has less data) to stay for the whole video.

```
    gg_df <- 
  tibble(
    frame = 1:100,
    x = 1:100,
    y = 1:100,
    object = rep(c('player_a', 'player_b'), 50)
  )

gg_bounces <- 
  tibble(
    frame = seq(1, 100, 10),
    x = seq(100, 1, -10),
    y = seq(1, 100, 10)
  )

p <- 
  ggplot() +  
  geom_point(data = gg_df, aes(x, -y, col = object)) +
  geom_point(data = gg_bounces, aes(x, -y), fill = 'red', col = 'red', size = 5) +
  transition_reveal(frame)

b <- animate(p, duration = 15, fps = 25, renderer = av_renderer(), height = 1000, width = 600, res = 170)

anim_save("output.mp4", b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to display the points from `gg_bounces` in each frame of the animation you have to drop or rename the `frame` column in this dataset.

Note: As is your example data and code did not work because of the different data types. That's why I convert the columns in `gg_bounces` to integers.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

gg_bounces[] <- lapply(gg_bounces, as.integer)
gg_bounces$frame <- NULL

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = gg_df, aes(x, -y, col = object)) +
  geom_point(data = gg_bounces, aes(x, -y), col = "red", size = 5) +
  transition_reveal(frame)
```

[image]

**EDIT** To show the points from `gg_bounces` too but keep them until the end of the animation we could follow the example in the docs and assign a unique group using `group = seq_along(frame)` (of course do we have to keep the `frame` column in this case as well):

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = gg_df, aes(x, -y, col = object)) +
  geom_point(
    data = gg_bounces, aes(x, -y, group = seq_along(frame)),
    col = "red", size = 5
  ) +
  transition_reveal(frame)
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want them to show up when their frame number is up and then stay until the end of the video?

Comment: See my edit on how this could be achieved.